# jQuery / PHP Allowing CORS

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using jQuery to check if a server is accessible from another server.

The  code I'm using to do this is :

```
urlExists(newUrl, function(exists) {
    console.log (exists)
});    

function urlExists(url, callback){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: url,
    success: function(){
      callback(true);
    },
    error: function() {
      callback(false);
    }
  });
}
```

This always results in:

```
HEAD http://192.168.0.209/test/ 401 (Unauthorized)
cors.php:1 Failed to load http://192.168.0.209/test/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.0.20' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

I've tried adding CORS header values to my `.htaccess` and my `.conf` for this site and I've run `a2enmod headers` nothing seems to help.

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

The .conf file is:

```
Alias /test /www/test/
<Directory "/www/test/">
DirectoryIndex index.php
AllowOverride All
Options +ExecCGI
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The .htaccess in /www/test is:

```
AuthUserFile /home/userA/.htpasswd
AuthName EnterPassword
AuthType Basic
<Limit GET POST>
require valid-user
</Limit>
```

Can someone advise how to get this to work ? I've read numerous examples on here, but none have helped.

Thanks

Comment: You do have access to the page you are trying to reach with ajax? Is it working if you add this in php to the page you are trying to call from the ajax call?

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

Comment: *The response had HTTP status code 401.* — indicates authentication is failing, right? If you want the eliminate the CORS error, then you need to make your Apache server send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header for 401 errors 4xx and 5xx errors. To do that use `always`, like this: `Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`. Then you won’t have CORS problem any longer. Instead you’ll still just have a 401 authentication failure.

Comment: Thanks that has helped with my issue